# postman (cURL) works, python PUT request doesn't

Tags: amazon-web-services, put, pre-signed-url

I got presigned url to aws s3 server and it works perfect in postman (via cURL) but if I try it in python I get signature error as response. Can you please help me with this issue (I am really frustrated).

cURL:

```
    curl --location --request PUT 'https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app.infrakit.com/file-service/2023/06-09/5fd12ab6-0775-4314-af2e-8561e80ddecc/080853/test4.xml?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEAaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJHMEUCIGt80CiQkmCRBfBB9v9tCtF5PjDGk8PRclLjjAzIrfbIAiEAx69qVx7m94aN%2BNUNw%2FwMu4qXdELPr1dwJx6KSP%2FVPycqwQUIiP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgwyNDM0MTQ2NTYzMTYiDM8rPdAHlfeDlAQgQyqVBQZmb7ztrQ9DxGyc2%2BhuZKklB%2Bzc8eUY4dZQQTV1gU0mFg26FYcwVzlUQ4FIznkEh3eYYryjCprR1X2a0YSfG8Nu%2BPYp%2BwMfpq5%2BjYmnryDuwNH5yksp92RmWBuyAoFNRBmGiEdiVpkXoPcUs04QmEoNLVzFQIQjt2I55UKmjSJgujJ0f5Ott%2FRgkjy%2BOtSMLhb%2Br%2BVa6xoz%2BbTzYnXMTbTEfiCvhLrwD4eGXTTIEJKZY227QSunkIosXBm9mseZLLoogNtYcLCa91BCOKw%2FJZWlAmhdal6eT2R3Xx%2BffCf3E458EG2If9z0kl%2B4qYcdFze%2BdGmVq6kU0UIgvFZWfk7qZ5cfZqec1R0iQxN20%2BdBcTww7X6LskSzcJMDXET00%2F3Ipa%2FRFGQEAZixNNd7qkDxdloiRMnebzagaqVB2QQ%2FylKgeIUUk6UyQO61t5dny0OyyxdnY5itBrzsJbHAC5L44m5LMNn6zxxve9OsC%2BsEsjjjuAXfQaQT09HzmRjyvk5HT3eMASddc0MM4JJFLZBO8ps%2BcBnmhfUMK71ip52AP58AxFXrNk2U1l%2FhE3AIDSnZ%2Fp2w1896sr3NyIqroBq5G%2FGoq%2Fl2Z1O78aOMy35a4NFJlKEReVlmv4dKXy%2BZ5IZPHdNRK7EurtVu8AuVuTwtHyF%2BepYBKw%2BzCY71aMklLSSvnKWMAfOAymUdZOKPkTCYkFCFxdPzsHIQ34xAwYuHsQ%2FDjQImZ0BGHZKNiQBbTO8wYjhkIx5HOVLR%2Bg1UOOmTCDNSUlKLYzFKg1XWy98kVQIZ%2F5OWtfkjW9PKDs9g3yobuwHSNYcnvQoRiOVNmCTWKI8nC23Lnm4ILd%2FKWNWxYCTQmMVeMuUvLZymMwlAyj3XVpMwoaKLpAY6sQF%2Bi%2BFMa1yT%2FlQDAF02eLkcHwwqSaZAHNUnr%2Bwccq24xeflNqK9ABL9sJ3zilPA8i1lpoNImU%2FmIkP47bjVcvvkDMXsSLmcvkL%2BCkZTZfxOaYJ%2BVNygkIYvUqBDbnqi7Ej2U%2B6Br32spEJHpMKBk6j6dMFrLAedV%2Bay3ZHQwTTFWRbHp7yBA3rovh3GVpprur5eOHcXby1Bc3uyOdodDP8v8JCn69oWcgmbBnOfQt2K6DU%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230609T080853Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-length%3Bcontent-md5%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Expires=54000&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATRLFE4U6ENC3PHSI%2F20230609%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=cade7013cb76ba9ccf38bf72a072a8b203cc2511c017d6fbff69af1c8da37c6f' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
--header 'Content-Length: 16817' \
--form 'file=test4.xml'
```

python:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    'Content-Length': '16817',
}

params = {
    'X-Amz-Security-Token': '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',
    'X-Amz-Algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
    'X-Amz-Date': '20230609T080853Z',
    'X-Amz-SignedHeaders': 'content-length;content-md5;content-type;host',
    'X-Amz-Expires': '54000',
    'X-Amz-Credential': 'ASIATRLFE4U6ENC3PHSI/20230609/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request',
    'X-Amz-Signature': 'cade7013cb76ba9ccf38bf72a072a8b203cc2511c017d6fbff69af1c8da37c6f',
}

files = {
    'file': open('test4.xml', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.put('https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app.infrakit.com/file-service/2023/06-09/5fd12ab6-0775-4314-af2e-8561e80ddecc/080853/test4.xml', params=params, headers=headers, files=files)
```